# Deciphering ODP.net-triggered stack trace error?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using ODP.net to connect to an Oracle schema, and keep triggering the following error trace:

```
   ORA-6413: Connection not open.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(
      Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(
      Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
```

I am at a complete loss to explain why the application I am working with cannot establish a connection.  My understanding of Oracle-specific error codes is limited, so any insight that can be shared is much appreciated.

I have tested the login credentials and TNS settings via logging into SQL+ plus, and those are correct.

The connection string format I am using is:

```
    user id=[userid];
    password=[password];
    data source=//[machine ID]:[port]/[service name]
```

I am using the 10.2.0.100 version of OracleDataAccess.dll.

I can provide additional information for anyone who dares to try to solve this.  Any input is much appreciated - I've been puzzling over this for far too long!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message: "ORA-6413: Connection not open." It's likely your code is simply neglecting to Open the database connection.

your code should look something like this:

```
using(OracleConnection _dbConnection = /*...setup connection object here...*/)
{
    _dbConnection.Open();
    var cmd = _dbConnection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText="some sql here";
    cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //... do "stuff" and then close your reader and connection...
}
```

Comment: I wish that were the issue. :-p  The error is getting triggered by the call to the .Open() function.